# Deleting Row from database and datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datarow

In datagridview I have one checkbox column ,row(s) in which checkbox is checked is/are should get deleted from datagridview as well as from database when i click on `delete` button ,I am using this code for doing this functionality ,using this code i am able to delete row from datagidview,but while deleting it from database i am getting this exception `Data type mismatch in criteria expression.` after this line of code `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` 
where i am going wrong,what correction should i do so that i get this working

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        List<int> ChkedRow=new List<int>();
        DataRow dr;
        List<int> ChkedRowQid=new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["select"].Value) == true)
        {
          ChkedRow.Add(i); 
            ChkedRowQid.Add(Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["QID"].Value));

        }
        }

        foreach (int k in ChkedRow)
        {
        dr = dt.Rows[k];
        dt.Rows[k].Delete();
            foreach(int j in ChkedRowQid)
            {
                bool flag=false;
            try 
            {
                string sql = "DELETE FROM Questions WHERE QID='" + j + "' ";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql,acccon);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                flag = true;
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {

            }

            }

        //dt.Rows.Remove(dr);
        }
```

Thanks In advance for any help

Comment: In your database, is QID a string or some type of integer?

Comment: since i am using Microsoft Access so  QID is Text type of integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code

```
Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["QID"].Value)
```

i can guess your `QID` is an integer whereas you are passing it as a string. You dont need single quotes around it.

```
string sql = "DELETE FROM Questions WHERE QID=" + j ;
```

should be good.

**Edit**:

Although this should work for you but this is not a recommended practice as you are vulnerable to `SQLInjection`. You should use parameterised query to run any script against your database. e.g.

```
using(OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString))
{
conn.Open();
string query= "DELETE FROM Questions WHERE QID = @pID";
OleDbCommand comamnd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
comamnd.Parameters.Add("@pID",OleDbType.Integer).Value = j;
comamnd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: @Durga what is the error? still same? or is simply not deleting?

Comment: @Durga Glad that it worked. But i would recommend you to use parameterized query. As your current code is vulnerable to sqlinjection

Comment: parameterised means as `Martijn van Put` has answered like that?

Comment: Yes that is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Best is to build up the OleDbCommand with Parameters.

```
 OleDbCommand oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM Questions WHERE QID = @QID", acccon);
 oleDbCommand.Parameters.Add("@QID",OleDbType.Integer).Value = j;
 oleDbCommand.Prepare();
 oleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: It is giving me exception `Prepare: Connection property has not been initialized.` at this line `oleDbCommand.Prepare();` how do i correct it?

Comment: Pass the connection to the OleDbCommand, i shall update my example.